# Keep bootstrap table-striped order with ng-if

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm generating `table` rows (`tr`) with `ng-repeat`.
Each row has a hidden row with details which is shown based on a Angular controller property.

Showing / hiding is done using `ng-if` (due to performance reasons inside the details view `ng-show` is not an option here)

```
<tr ng-click="select(ceo.name)" ng-repeat-start="ceo in ceos">
    <td>{{ceo.firstname}}</td>
    <td>{{ceo.lastname}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-if="selected==ceo.name" ng-click="deselect()" ng-repeat-end>
    <td colspan=2>{{ceo.firstname}} Details</td>
</tr>
```

The problem is: the table uses `table table-striped` CSS classes.
When details are shown, the order of the stripes is shifted so the details now has the background color of the row of the next `ceo` and so on.

How can I keep the order of the background-colors and make the details have the same background-color as the "master" row?

Nesting `table` should be avoided.

The pen goes [here](https://codepen.io/AlexZeitler/pen/GOywLo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something :

**Codepen**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aVEXRw

**CSS**:

```
.table-striped-ang > tbody > tr[data-index="0"] {
    background-color: grey; //rgb(249, 249, 249);
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.12/angular.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table class="table table-striped-ang">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Firstname</td>
        <td>Lastname</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-click="select(ceo.name)" data-index="{{$index%2}}" ng-repeat-start="ceo in ceos">
        <td>{{ceo.firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{ceo.lastname}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-if="selected==ceo.name" data-index="{{$index%2}}" ng-click="deselect()" ng-repeat-end>
        <td colspan=2>{{ceo.firstname}} Details</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```